# Is there a way to deploy Airflow with Docker but using different workers?

Tags: docker, airflow, environment, worker

I have an Airflow deployment using docker-compose as explained on the official Airflow documentation ([here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html)).

I am asking myself if it is possible to create a setup that allows different python environments for different tasks. I.e. let's say I have a pipeline for project 1 which has conflicting dependencies with the DAGs of project 2.

Is there a way to just create two different worker images and somehow tell Airflow to which worker container the corresponding tasks should be sent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not go with workflow specific Airflow images, because the approach does not scale. That is, if you had, for example, ten workflows with custom Airflow-worker images each, and you decided to upgrade Airflow, you would have to upgrade each of those custom images.

To deal with conflicting dependencies in Python environments, there are [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html). Airflow has [PythonVirtualenvOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html#pythonvirtualenvoperator) that allows executing Python callables inside a new Python virtual environment containing exactly the dependencies the callable needs. This way, in the same workflow (DAG), you can have multiple tasks with completely different set of dependencies each.